# Using position to count nodes - sometimes enumeration starts at 0 instead of 1

Tags: xml, xslt

Hey folks,
 I've got this rather clumbsy piece of xslt which I use to transform SOAPUI test cases into a more readable format. Currently it enumerates the test cases using the following

`<xsl:value-of select="position()-3"/>`

**My question** Sometimes the test case enumeration starts at 0 and sometimes it starts at 1. I don't understand why this is happening? Is it something to do with how the position selector is implemented? Is there a neater way to count instances of a node?

Many thanks,

*Richard*

Here is the code in its entirety - sans styling.

`

```
  <!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding ="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggleDiv(divid){
                var ele = document.getElementById(divid);

                if(ele.style.display == 'none')
                    { 
                        ele.style.display = 'block';
                    }
                else
                    {
                        ele.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
          </script>  

            <style type="text/css"></style>

        </head>

        <body>

          <xsl:apply-templates/>

          <div class="help">This report is generated automatically by a scheduled job running on Richard Fortune's machine. The SOAPUI project files it references are located in sourcecontrol SVN (https://svn.xxx.xxxxxx.com/svn/network/TEST). These reports are generated daily as the projects they reference are subject to change.</div>

        </body>
      </html>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="con:soapui-project">
     <div><h1>Project Name : <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h1></div> 
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="con:testSuite">    

    <xsl:if test="con:description=''">
                <p class="warn"> (RICHARD - PLEASE PROVIDE A DESCRIPTION!!)</p>
    </xsl:if>       
      <div id="content" onmousedown="toggleDiv('{position()}');"><h2 class="ex">TestSuite:  <xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2></div>
      <br>
        <p class="descSuite"><b>Suite Description: </b><xsl:value-of select="con:description"/></p>
      </br>

      <div style="display:none" id="{position()}"><xsl:apply-templates />
      </div>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="con:testCase">

        <ul>
          <li class="tc"><b>
            (#<xsl:value-of select="position()-3"/>) Testcase: </b><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </li>

          <xsl:if test="con:description=''">
            <p class="warn">(Gentle reminder Richard - PLEASE PROVIDE A DESCRIPTION!!)</p>
          </xsl:if>

          <p class="descTc">
            <strong><i>Description:</i></strong> <xsl:value-of select="con:description"/>
          </p>
          <ol class="step">
          <xsl:for-each select="con:testStep"><li>TestStep: <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> </li></xsl:for-each>
          </ol>

        </ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates />

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="*"></xsl:template>


  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

`

Comment: It would be useful have a sample of your XML input.

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide a complete (but as short as possible) XML document. Also provide the wrong result you are getting and explain what the correct result should be. I think I know what the problem might be, but I don't want to spent my time guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would use `<xsl:number>`, which is more efficient than using `count()`:

```
<li class="tc">
  <b>(#<xsl:number/>) Testcase: </b><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
</li>
```

It's that simple! By default, `<xsl:number>` counts the nodes of the same node kind (in this case, elements) and the same element name as the context node... which is what you want here, I believe. So it will count `<con:testCase>` elements.

Comment: Hi Lars, I tried this first and it worked perfectly "out-of-the-box". Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `count()`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*)+1"/>
```

This returns the current position of the node respect to all its sibling elements (1-based).

`position()` might be not the proper way depending on the context.

Comment: *'This returns the current position of the node respect to all its siblings (1-based).'* - actually with respect to all its preceding sibling **elements**. This is a critical distinction, because the problem the OP is having with `position()` is that it is counting all preceding sibling nodes, including those that are not elements, such as whitespace text nodes.

Comment: yes, that's why `count` is better. The XPath I've provided will count only the previous sibling elements. What's the OP is searching for then?

Comment: I believe you're right about what the OP is searching for, and your XPath does the right thing. I was just pointing out that your description "[with] respect to all its siblings" is misleading; I believe you meant "[with] respect to all its sibling **elements**" (i.e. excluding sibling text nodes, comments, etc.).

Comment: Hi Empo, I also tried the example you gave above. I had to modify it slightly to calibrate the count. I have gone with the sample LarsH provided given it worked for me straight away. However I do prefer the precision of the approach you suggest and will keep this in my box of tricks for future reference! Thanks for your response!

Comment: @richfort: Welcome, please upvote to increase reputation of my answer if you like, so that other users may relay on that.

Comment: +1 since you corrected the sentence (and supplied a working solution in the first place). `count()` certainly has some advantages over `<xsl:number>`, especially transparency: you don't have to know a lot about default behaviors in order to be able to predict what it's going to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `position()` is it can (and frequently does) include nodes you don't expect, such as text or even whitespace nodes, if whatever read the XML preserved it.

Depending on your precise requirements, you can count the number of preceding siblings (as @empo described), or it might be worth looking into the `<xsl:number>` instruction.

Comment: Good points; but the use of terms is incorrect and confusing: contrary to what your answer implies, the term *elements* does **not** include text or whitespace nodes; whereas *text nodes* **do** include whitespace nodes.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `<xsl:number>`, which is usually much more efficient than `count()`. -1 for incorrect terminology.

Comment: Yeah, true. I blame .NET, I'm too used to using `SelectSingleNode` when I'm searching for elements; I know it can return other nodes as well of course, but I got into the bad habit of thinking of nodes/elements as the same thing. Old habits die hard. I'll amend the answer.